# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, selenium

```
package com.Pack;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TextBoxDemo {
    //Launch the browser
    //enter valid url
    //enter data in to text box

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // System.setProperty("webdriver.c  rome.driver",
        //  "/Users/adeshpansuriya/Downloads/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }   
}
```

Comment: there is problem with jar

Comment: I can not add external jar file while same program works in other mac

Comment: Show more info, and what have you tried before.

Comment: Setting system properties like that is a bad idea.  You may end up setting the property after it has been read; e.g. if it is consulted during class initialization.  Try setting the property with a `-D` command line option.  If that doesn't help, update your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including the command line you are using to run the example.